# i dont know why the isset function is not working when i submit

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<?php

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
    mysql_select_db ('product');
    echo "Connected to database";
    session_start();
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Register</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reg.css" />

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center">
<td>
<tr>
    <div align="center" style="size:30%;" class="container">
            <div class="row main" style="width:30%;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                   <div class="panel-title text-center">
                        <h1 class="title">Register Here</h1>
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="main-login main-center">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php 
         echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

                        <div align="left" class="form-group">
                            <label name="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  placeholder="Enter your Name"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div align="left" class="form-group">
                            <label name="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Email</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"   placeholder="Enter your Email"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div align="left" class="form-group">
                            <label name="user_name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name"   placeholder="Enter your Username"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div align="left" class="form-group">
                            <label name="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"   placeholder="Enter your Password"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div align="left" class="form-group">
                            <label name="confirm_password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password"   placeholder="Confirm your Password"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>enter code here

                        <div align="left" class="form-group ">
                            <button  type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="login-register">
                            <a href="log.php">Already registered? Login here</a>
                         </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </tr>
    </td>
</table>






<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['confirm_password'];
    $slquery = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = '$email'";
    $selectresult = mysql_query($slquery);
    if(empty($_POST['name']))
                    {
                        $nameErr='Enter Your Name!';
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $user = test_input($_POST['name']);
                        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/',$user))
                            {
                                $nameErr=' Re-Enter Your Name! Format Inccorrect!( only alpha, numbers,@_ are allowed)';
                            }
                    }
                    if(empty($_POST['password']))
                    {
                        $passErr='Enter Your Password!';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $user = test_input($_POST['password']);
                        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/',$pass))
                        {
                            $passErr='Invalid Format! Re-Enter Password!';
                        }
                    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectresult)>0)
    {
         $msg = 'email already exists';
    }
    elseif($password != $cpassword){
         $msg = "passwords doesn't match";
    }
    else{
          $query = "INSERT INTO customer (name,email,user_name, password,confirm_password, ) VALUES ('
          $name', '$username', '$password', '$cpassword', '$email')";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          if($result){
             $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
          }
    }
   }

?>


</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a registration form with validation.i used some bootstrap for the front end design then Mysql database along with php.

when I click to submit the registration form, it does not validate the field values.please, someone, tell me what's wrong with this.Also, it's not showing the errors. I don't know why this is not working.

```
Thank you in Advance.
```

Comment: why are you using `htmlspecialchars` in form action?

Comment: use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and show us an error

Comment: Plus, use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead of these old deprecated functions

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function test_input() on line 129... This is the error is shows......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line from

```
<button  type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register</button>
```

to

```
<button  type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register</button>
```

You have used `button` so form is not submitted. Change it to `submit` type

**EDIT**

**Note**: please start using PDO or mysqli

Please check below point:

1) You have used `test_input()` but not defined in your shown code.

2) Your query have extra `,` after `confirm_password`.

3) Insert query will not work. There were some errors:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer (name,user_name, password,confirm_password, email) VALUES ('
          $name', '$username', '$password', '$cpassword', '$email')";
```

4) No need to store confirm_password

Comment: Thank you Jigar shah, it worked when the changed it's type...but it shows some error where i didnt use any function

Comment: can you please edit your post and paste the error, so we can help you. Also make sure have error reporting on

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function test_input() on line 129...... This is the error it shows ...

Answer (score 0):

**Database**

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "stackoverflow";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
    session_start();
?>
```

**Change the Register button like this**

```
<div align="left" class="form-group ">
                        <button  type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register</button>
                    </div>
```

**test_function**

```
  function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
  }
```

**Full PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$cpassword = $_POST['confirm_password'];
$slquery = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = '$email'";
$selectresult = mysqli_query($conn,$slquery);
 if(empty($_POST['name']))
                {
                    $nameErr='Enter Your Name!';
                }
                else 
                {
                    $user = test_input($_POST['name']);
                  if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/',$user))
                        {
                            $nameErr=' Re-Enter Your Name! Format 
    Incorrect!( only alpha, numbers,@_ are allowed)';
                        }
                }
                if(empty($_POST['password']))
                {
                    $passErr='Enter Your Password!';
                }
                else
                {
                    $user = test_input($_POST['password']);
                    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/',$password))
                    {
                        $passErr='Invalid Format! Re-Enter Password!';
                    }
                }

 if (mysqli_num_rows($selectresult)>0)
    {
     echo 'email already exists';
    }               

elseif($password != $cpassword){
     $msg = "passwords doesn't match";
}
else{

      var_dump($name.$email.$username.$password.$cpassword);
      $query = "INSERT INTO customer(name,email,user_name, 
      password,confirm_password) VALUES ('
      $name', '$email','$username', '$password', '$cpassword')";
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo "New user created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}?>
```

Comment: i have done everything as per your suggested code...but it does not validating the input values.....

Comment: I only changed the database connection code,test_input function,the submit button and the INSERT INTO database part, the rest is your code.I think its your duty to do the rest of the work. Don't you think so?

Comment: of course, yes its my job ...i just wanted to know whether am i going on the right way.....